# Ajax autocomplete Extender prevent to type invalid value in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

am using `Ajax AutoCompleteExtender` in `asp textbox` as below.

it's working fine but,
**Problem:** when user type text which is invalid or not match from the database value, it should show a message to user like "keyword not matched..."

**Code**

```
<asp:HiddenField id ="hdnFieldValue" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtContactsSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="2"
    CompletionInterval="100" OnClientItemSelected="ClientItemSelected" UseContextKey="true" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" 
    TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch"
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**Java Script Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ClientItemSelected(sender, e) {
            $get(e.get_value());
            $get("<%=hdnFieldValue.ClientID %>").value = e.get_value();
        }
    </script>
```

I am get value using above javascript method into `asp hidden field`. But I want to set `Empty` into hidden field when user type invalid text

Please give me suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ADD IN YOUR AUTOEXTENDER :

```
  <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender   ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers"  OnClientPopulated="ClientPopulated" 
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

JS : From below you can highlight your Text with result,same way you can check for text

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function ClientPopulated(source, args) {
        if (source._currentPrefix != null) {
            var list = source.get_completionList();

            var search = source._currentPrefix.toLowerCase();

            for (var i = 0; i < list.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var text = list.childNodes[i].innerHTML;
                var index = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(search);
                if (index != -1) {
                    var value = text.substring(0, index);  

   </script>
```